# Accessing raw files on GitHub using a URL + token

Tags: url, github, gradle, token

In a Gradle script I have referenced a file directly on my GitHub account like so:

```
buildscript { scriptHandler ->
    apply from: 'https://github.com/raw/foo/bar-repo/master/repos.gradle?token=DFXD68SDF9DFKvNY-801UJHUHDUVdsd782MewA%3fks5D%3D', to: scriptHandler

    dependencies {
        // some dependencies
    }
}
```

I got the URL by going to the "Raw" link on my GitHub page for the file in question.

When I run a local build everything works perfectly and my build can retrieve the raw file referenced with the URL that contains an access token.

Are there any dangers to this (I am keeping the URL private within my org). Will the token expire? I want to share common configuration such as URLs within the buildscript block, and this seems to be the simplest way of doing it.

EDIT:
I've gone to the Security section of my GitHub account and revoked all sessions and logged out (to end my current session). The URL still works.

Comment: Is that a real token?

Comment: No, I messed around with it before I posted it here on Stackoverflow. But assume it is real :)

Comment: @Boon, it this still working for you?

Comment: Unfortunately I am no longer using this mechanism to retrieve the file. However, I did receive confirmation from GitHub that tokens in raw URLs expire after a period of time, how long they did not specify.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Yeah, I just had the experience of these tokens expiring after ~1 week.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827530/github-get-on-private-repo-with-access-token