# Github GET on private repo with access token

Tags: git, github

I have a private repo in my org and I need to provide access. I want to be able to access a file through a GET request (the browser). I do NOT have a terminal or curl or any other tools.

I created a dummy account that I linked to my org. I went to https://github.com/settings/tokens and added one.

Then I tried the following URLS

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ORG/REPO/master/path/to/file.json?private_token=26cb4d8a30ca2
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ORG/REPO/master/path/to/file.json?token=26cb4d8a30ca2

which does not work. It only seems to work with the generated token that you get when you click on "raw" on the github gui. Unfortunately this token expires quickly so it does not work for my application.

How do I access private resource on github with an access token through a URL ?

Comment: " I do NOT have a terminal or curl or any other tools." Too bad: it should work with curl: https://gist.github.com/Integralist/9482061

Answer (score 5):

The [API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/#oauth2-token-sent-as-a-parameter) list that you can use the parameter `access_token` to pass in an oauth token (not `private_token` or `token`).

Does https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ORG/REPO/master/path/to/file.json?access_token=26cb4d8a30ca2 work for you?

Comment: Hi. I get `404 not found`. It might be that I generate the token through the `personnal access token` menu instead of the `oAuth Applications` menu. Ill report back.

Comment: nope it doesnt work. The `oAuth applications` menu seems to be something entirely different as it generates a `clientID` and a `clientSecret`

Comment: Bah, that's a pain, I thought it would work since the personal access token page says "Personal access tokens function like ordinary OAuth access tokens".

Comment: Maybe it's because raw.githubusercontent.com is not under the API. There is an API method for getting the content, but to get the raw file, you need to request a custom media type (which you can't do through the browser) so that won't work for your either. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents

Comment: Yes and that is what I am investigating. I managed to access my repo through a GET request with `https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/contents/README.md?ref=master&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN`. Unfortunately this only gives me an answer that describes the file i.e. `{
  "name": "README.md",
  "path": "README.md",
  "sha": "071ce7145e881eb36b48a8acb2849720d914d468",
  "size":, etc`

Comment: actually, and to complete my above comment, there is a `contents` field which contains the base64 encoded contents of the file. Unfortunately I have no access to terminal so I cannot decode it to UTF-8... Do you know of any way to get the raw content through the api.github.com interface with my personnal token?

Comment: To get the raw content, you need to set the `Accept` header to `application/vnd.github.v3.raw`. However, I don't know of any way to do that through a browser.

Comment: When I do this it says "Not Acceptable 406"

Comment: @bny you should also get a "download_url" field that you can use to download the file (you will have to do another call).

Answer (score 3):

To fetch raw use:

```
curl \
  -H 'Authorization: token <personal token gen value>' \
  https://raw.<host>/user/org/repo/pathtofile
```

To fetch through api:

```
curl \
  -H 'Authorization: token <personal token gen>' \
  -H 'Accept:application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw' \
  https://<host_name>/api/v3/repos/<user>/<repo_name>/contents/<path_to_file>/?ref=<branch>
```

Comment: Can we get clarification on VERSION (line 4.)?
Also how do we determine the path_to_file ?

Comment: Version is plain text http header it does not point to any specific version. For path, you need the relative path from root of your repository to your file.

Comment: Cheers, in a browser this includes 'blob' and 'master', and for raw in a browser the (no API) hostname is raw.githubusercontent.com. I am not getting any joy from filename.ext.  I am using https://raw.github.com/xxxx/project/filename.ext  and I have no org? It's driving me up the wall.

Comment: Figured out the token does not have read access  to private repos, despite requesting this. Full control seems to be required. Something like execute being required on folders....